# How do I make the Checkbox in Android CheckedTextView be left aligned instead of right aligned?

Tags: android

I am trying to use R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice with ListView.  CheckedTextView is used in simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml, but how can I make the checkbox be left aligned instead of right aligned?

Answer (score 44):

The secret is in android:checkMark make it null

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/checked_text_single_choice"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="52dp"
android:checkMark="@null"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:drawableRight="@null"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
/>
```

Comment: checkMark is a drawable and setting @ null to it does nothing but removes the checkmark drawable. So this solution does not work. Instead, use the  android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
attribute as suggested by @Roger Keays

Answer (score 36):

Create your own row template and set android:drawableLeft on the CheckedTextView.

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
/>
```

or

```
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

Comment: That prevents you from using the compound drawable functionality together with the check mark indicator (which CheckedTextView by default allows). I think @CommonsWare answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

If you want the checkbox to be on the left, simply just use a [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html). Maybe it is not matter of course, but a `CheckBox` can contain text. You can define that text by adding an XML attribute [android:text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atext), or by calling the [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method. Actually `CheckBox` is inherited from `Button`, which inherits from `TextView`, that's why it has all the text-related properties.

Comment: added example `CheckBox` xml with screenshot in separate answer

Answer (score 10):

I don't think you can. Looking at the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java&q=package:android%20checkedtextview&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc), it seems like the checkmark is drawn on the right all the time. And, to be honest, I would recommend you stick with that, for consistency -- Android gets knocked all the time because its apps have inconsistent UIs.

In the off chance that somebody is pointing a gun at your head, forcing you to change the placement of the checkmark, subclass `CheckedTextView` as `OMGPleaseDontShootCheckedTextView`, and override methods like `onDraw()`, with tweaked versions of the original that changes the placement of the image and text.

Comment: Now with Material design checkmarks should be on the left, but the code to allow this is unfortunately private so cannot be easily backported.

Comment: Checkmark on the left in MAterial Design https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#usage. I'm sick of Android to this missfinctionality

Answer (score 5):

You can assign your drawable to drawableLeft attribute, but it won't make you any good because it not support tinting.
Instead I extended CheckedTextView like that:

```
public class LeftSideCheckedTextView extends CheckedTextView {

    public LeftSideCheckedTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public LeftSideCheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public LeftSideCheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Field mCheckMarkGravity = null;
        try {
            mCheckMarkGravity = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mCheckMarkGravity");
            mCheckMarkGravity.setAccessible(true);
            mCheckMarkGravity.set(this, Gravity.START);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I access the hidden field mCheckMarkGravity which is used inside CheckedTextView but have no access via style attributes, according to this bug ticket: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174517

Answer (score 4):

An example of @WonderCsabo's suggestion to use CheckBox.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/create_account_checkedTextView_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:checked="true"

    # relative layout params
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/hint1" />
```

[image: checkbox_example]

Answer (score 2):

There can be a trick with Checkable Layout like in this post - https://chris.banes.me/2013/03/22/checkable-views/
. Just use some custom layout like this as ListView item layout:

```
<com.example.custom_view.CheckableLinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    .../>
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .../>
</com.example.custom_view.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

or

```
android:checkMark=?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

Answer (score 2):

---

Looking at the source, it's just based on layout direction. Setting it to RTL works well enough for me.

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Source:

```
   private boolean isCheckMarkAtStart() {
    final int gravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(mCheckMarkGravity, getLayoutDirection());
    final int hgrav = gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
    return hgrav == Gravity.LEFT;
}
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    ...

        final boolean checkMarkAtStart = isCheckMarkAtStart();
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int top = y;
        final int bottom = top + height;
        final int left;
        final int right;
        if (checkMarkAtStart) {
            left = mBasePadding;
            right = left + mCheckMarkWidth;
        } else {
            right = width - mBasePadding;
            left = right - mCheckMarkWidth;
        }
        ...

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one and hope it will give you some ideas

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Connection lost sound alert"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"     
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"                 
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution without making a Checkbox in the layout. Try the solution here.

[Android ListView ArrayAdapter - checkbox/radio button arrangement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640791/android-listview-arrayadapter-checkbox-radio-button-arrangement/51679394#51679394)

Answer (score -3):

Adding this line makes checkbox on left

```
 android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```