# Change position of radiobuttons in ListView

Tags: android

I have a little problem. I have a ListView and I use:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
        data);
```

to have list with single choice. But in this solution I have a radio buttons on right side, but I want to have them on left side. How can I do that?

Edit:
My xml File:

```
<LinearLayout     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="92.5">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_account_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:text="@string/user_account_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login" 
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout xml file

Comment: use a custom adapter and inflate a custom layout with checkbox or radio button. you can define custom layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create new `xml` layout and copy the source code of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` ([here](https://code.google.com/p/android-binding/source/browse/trunk/AndroidBindingMarkupDemo/res/layout/simple_list_item_single_choice.xml?r=309))

Then,

1. Change `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"` to `android:checkMark="@null"`
2. Add new line:
   `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"` 
   or if you want checkboxes, then use this one: 
   `android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`
3. Use this new layout in your code: 
   `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.YOUR_NEW_XML, data);`

This thread could be helpful for you: [How do I make the Checkbox in Android CheckedTextView be left aligned instead of right aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114745/how-do-i-make-the-checkbox-in-android-checkedtextview-be-left-aligned-instead-of)

Answer (score 1):

Use your simple adapter and your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,data,R.layout.main,new String[]{""},new int[]{R.id.txt});
>
> list.setAdapter(adapter);