# how to modify style of simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a simple listview  with ***`simple_list_item_multiple_choice`***

```
lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.files_list_view);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,readyToDownload );
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

[image]

but here the checkboxes are on right side by default **i want to place them before text on left side**. how is it possible, i am avoiding custom adapter

Comment: Duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114745/how-do-i-make-the-checkbox-in-android-checkedtextview-be-left-aligned-instead-of

Comment: Use Custom Adatper. You will have better control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply done by creating custom row template

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
/>

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,R.layout.simple_list_item,readyToDownload );
```