# Android ListView ArrayAdapter - checkbox/radio button arrangement

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Is there a way to rearrange the checkboxes so that it appears before the text?

I am using ArrayAdapter with `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, ideally, I would like to see the checkboxes at the start, with the text following after.

Or should I make a custom adapter to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114745/how-do-i-make-the-checkbox-in-android-checkedtextview-be-left-aligned-instead-of

Comment: Yea, they make a custom checktextbox row for the adapter, i guess by default the arrayadapter does it in a specific way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the alignment.

After `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`

use `listView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);`

works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

In the adapter, you could use a custom layout such as:

*Construction of the array adapter*

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item);
```

*XML File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

In that case, the XML is a simple TextView, but it could be more complex. So, you could control the layout of your adapter in a more customized way.